# Difference between masquerade and pretend

Tags: word-usage

What is the difference between masquerade and pretend?

Collins dictionary has the following example:
He masqueraded as a doctor and fooled everyone

Why can't we use pretend in this sentence.

Thanks.

Comment: The AHD/Collins senses 'to dissemble / to take part in an involved scheme' at least inform how one interprets 'to masquerade'; 'pretend' is far less marked.

Answer (score 2):

The very simplest answer is that we can use either word for the same basic idea:  it would be phrased "He **pretended to be** a doctor . . ." or even "He pretended he had a medical degree, and fooled everyone."

But here's my two-cent semantic digging a little deeper:
It seems to me that 'masquerade' is fundamentally about masking - that is, hiding one's 'true identity' - but no elaboration as far as the mask itself, i.e. there is no implied substitute for what is hidden.
It could be argued that the stereotypical 'masquerade ball' is about an elaborate substitute for the face, and that the interactions focus on a range of dynamic options:  what people can get away with saying when nobody can see them, how certain conventions are either relaxed or reinforced by curiosity and/or obfuscation, etc.  But sometimes it's more about who's been holding the most ostentatious or profoundly inspiring object in front of their face.

Whereas 'pretend' relates to pretense, pretension, pretentious, in that there is typically an intent to persuade/show observers something (e.g., "everything is fine, move along" or "I know what I'm doing") or a mutual intent to act out, roleplay etc. ("let's play pretend").  (or a combination of the two!)

Masquerade doesn't necessitate such an idea - it can simply be "you don't know who I am" and can even be a cheeky "I am not who I appear to be".  But in the bare context of the question, it is just another way of communicating a pretense.

The overlap is that both concepts *can* have an element of pretense, but the more masquerade is used as a verb synonymous with "pretend", the more the two ideas become muddled.

https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=masquerade :

> 1590s, "assembly of people wearing masks and disguises," from French
>   *mascarade* or Spanish *mascarada* "masked party or dance," from Italian
>   *mascarata* "a ball at which masks are worn," variant of *mascherata*
>   "masquerade," from *maschera* (see **mask** (n.)). Figurative sense of
>   "false outward show" is from 1670s.

https://www.etymonline.com/word/pretend :

> pretend (v.)
>   late 14c., "to profess, assert, maintain" (a claim, etc.), "to direct (one's) efforts," from Old French *pretendre* "to lay claim," from Latin *praetendere* "stretch in front, put forward, allege," from *prae* "before" (see pre-) + *tendere* "to stretch," from PIE root *ten- "to stretch."
>
> Main modern sense of "feign, put forward a false claim" is recorded from c. 1400; the older sense of simply "to claim" is behind the string of royal pretenders (1690s) in English history. Meaning "to play, make believe" is recorded from 1865. In 17c. pretend also could mean "make a suit of marriage for," from a sense in French. Related: **Pretended**; **pretending**.

Comment: +1. I think worth putting in a couple of quotes into this answer from etymonline as it would complement your observations. I 100% agree for comparing these words like these the etymology of the words gives very interesting insights.

Comment: I added a 2nd quote, N. Presley, any concerns feel free to revert my edit!

Comment: Not at all, I appreciate the follow-through.  I was so caught up with unpacking masquerade, I kinda forgot I was comparing it to anything else!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, *pretend* can be used as an adjective to denote something that is imaginary

> The children poured out pretend tea for the dolls.

whereas *masquerade* cannot be.

Coming onto their usage as verbs:
In some cases, the two can be used interchangeably like,

> - At the party, he was pretending to be Voldemort.
> - At the party, he was masquerading as Voldemort.

However, the latter is considered more apt.

The two words as verbs essentially mean the same thing, i.e., pulling a disguise, but are used in different contexts.

In the example you provide, we can use *pretend* although generally, *masquerade* is more suitable when the subject carries an illicit pursuit as in the case here. However, I do admit I may be going out on a limb here.

Also, we cannot use *masquerade* in such a sentence:

> He pretended to be asleep.

Comment: Excellent point - actively 'masquerading' is about being an impostor - some*one* you are not - rather than a feigned state.

Comment: Precisely! Yes, I think that sums it up perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can. The Cambridge dictionary defines the verb [masquerade](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/masquerade) as "to pretend or appear to be." So the following two sentences mean the same thing.

> He masqueraded as a doctor and fooled everyone.
>
> He pretended to be a doctor and fooled everyone.

However it doesn't work for this pair.

> He pretended to be angry.
>
> He masqueraded to be angry.

Comment: But you could say "He masqueraded anger".

Comment: I'd only normally use 'He pretended to be a doctor and fooled everyone.' if the situation was comic rather than serious. Register is important.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, I think the courts would probably describe it as "medical impersonation". [This report in *The Guardian*](https://www.theguardian.com/global/2017/aug/14/trust-me-im-a-fake-doctor-how-medical-imposters-thrive-in-the-real-world) talks about "medical imposters".  But you might say something like "He made himself out to be a doctor..." or "He affected to be a doctor..." Only if describing it to a child would you use "pretend".